# Filter Arabic Words Using PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, arabic

We have some accounts in the Active Directory with an Arabic display name and we want to change it to English, but I don't know how to get these accounts first using PowerShell. I use Quest ActiveRoles to query the Active Directory

```
Get-QADUser -SizeLimit 0 -SearchRoot "OU Location" | ? {$_.displayName -contains "The Arabic Letter Filter"}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could test with a regular expression to find Arabic letters in the names. The following would yield `True` because of the Arabic letter (`ـأ`) in the middle of the word:

```
"Blaـأ‎Bla" -match "\p{IsArabic}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much